# How do you print one fewer letters each time?

Tags: python

I need a program that prints one fewer letters each time.

For example:

```
BEAR
BEA
BE
B
```

Comment: SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_data="BEAR"
for i in range(len(my_data)):
    print(my_data[:len(my_data)-i]) #trick is here
```

Output:

```
BEAR
BEA
BE
B
```

Comment: thanks and sorry for asking a bad question

Comment: Okay, hope you will will do great in the future. If my answer does your work then you can accept it by pressing on the tick mark.